# Change base values to Any Height Any Width on Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, radix

So I've spent a lot of time creating an app and I noticed that I've been building it on a compact width and any height base values. Can I keep my changes and set it to any width and any height? Because now when I change it to that all my changes have disappeared. (my changes are EVERYTHING, I started making the app using compact width and any height)

Or will I need to switch to any width any height and restart my entire app? :(

please help

Comment: If all else fails, you can probably edit the xib manually and make some minimal changes to cause everything to apply to Any/Any.

Comment: Should be possible; try this: Go to your Storyboard. On the `Attributes` tab of the `Utilities` pane (the right-hand pane) towards the bottom is an untitled section for every object and constraint. Make sure every object & constraint is `installed` (ticked) for `Any Width` and `Any Height`. This is known as `Size Class Customization` if you want to search for the documentation online.

Answer (score 0):

A size class doesn’t necessarily map to one device in one orientation. For example, an iPad can have a view with an iPhone style layout (i.e. compact) when presented in a smaller space and an iPad style layout (i.e. regular) when the space is larger.

This means you can have a unified storyboard when building a universal application.

If you think there's anything wrong with it you can disable some constraints. These constraints won't apply to your current layout but still work for others. You can add some new constraints and the new constraints will work at the current size class.